# What plant resembles a tomato plant with thorns?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

What plant resembles a tomato plant with thorns? The leaves are similar to watermelon, but the plant and flowers look like a tomato plant.

Comment: Please add a photograph to your question; it will make identification much easier. Also, with [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Tomatoes are members of the *Solanum* genus, which consists of ~ 1,500-2,000 species. Many of these species have thorns and flowers similar to a tomato. Do any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=solanum%20thorns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=9SaGU6vNGuvJsQSO_4HQBg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1262&bih=950) look similar to the plant you saw?

Answer (score 3):

The plant from the Solanum genus with leaves similar to a watermelon plant, with thorns, and resembles a tomato would be a Silverleaf Nightshade.  It is a fairly common weed in the US.

[image: Silverleaf Nightshade]

Comment: The leaves don't look like watermelon though.